# Convert a list into a dictionary keeping the sequence intact

Tags: list, python-2.7, dictionary, type-conversion

I have a huge list and want to convert it into a dictionary like this.
Sample list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']
Output dictionary: {'a':'b', 'c':'d', 'e':'f', 'g':'h'}
I want the sequence to be intact. I read another post similar to it which uses izip from itertools. I tried using it as:

```
from itertools import izip
i = iter(list_name)
dic = dict(izip(i, i))
```

But it gives me a dictionary with all sequence jumbled.
Also, the list has even number of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*dicts* are *unordered* you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) to maintain insertion order:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

from itertools import izip
i = iter(list_name)
dic = OrderedDict(izip(i, i))
```

Output:

```
In [3]: list_name =  ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h']    
In [4]: i = iter(list_name)   
In [5]: dic = OrderedDict(izip(i, i))   
In [6]: dic
Out[6]: OrderedDict([('a', 'b'), ('c', 'd'), ('e', 'f'), ('g', 'h')]
```